# Integer division and scaling an input

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

I'm trying to get my head around integer division. I'm entering a decimal number between 100 and 6300 into my program, I then need to scale this number by 100 and output the result as a 6-bit number.

Mathematically what I'm trying to do is:

Output = Input/100

Very simple! But I just can't seem to get this to work in C. I'm using MikroC for a PIC18 MCU.

Example code:

```
int input;
int output;

void main(){
TRISA = 0x00;
input = 1000;//operator has input 1000
output = input/100.0;//scale input by 100
PORTA = output;//output 6-bit number
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? What did you expect it to do? What did it actually do?

Comment: I notice input is defined as an int, but you are dividing by a float 100.0. What does your particular compiler do with mixed mode arithmetic?

Comment: If I watch the output variable with the above code, output = 0

Comment: I have used PIC compilers where an int was 8 bits.  Don't know about this one.

Comment: The "input" is a variable defined, or is it nd input from external world

Comment: Why do you divide due a float value instead of an integer?

Comment: Input is from a keypad, but for debugging I'm defining it as variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no need for float division here at all, if you're just going to cast the result to an integer and write to a port. The result of your float division will be truncated to yield an integer, so you might do integer arithmetic.

```
unsigned int input;
unsigned char output;

void main(){
  TRISA = 0x00;
  input = 1000;//operator has input 1000
  output = input/100;//scale input by 100
  PORTA = output;//output 6-bit number

  while (1);  //while away once the program is done
}
```

For implementation independence, you can include `stdint.h` and use `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` to define `output` and `input` respectively, though thats hardly necessary here. If you do want the benefits of float division, you have to *round*.

```
#include <math.h>

unsigned int input;
unsigned char output;

void main(){
  TRISA = 0x00;
  input = 1000;
  output = round((double)input/100.0);  // implicit cast to uchar
  PORTA = output;

  while (1);  //while away once the program is done
}
```

I should mention that this latter approach is more costly than the former, since its floating point arithmetic. Use this only if you need the additional accuracy.

EDIT:

A compromise would be to add an offset to `input` and then dividing; this increases the accuracy of your results by simulating rounding with integer math. Its a lot more efficient than the floating point option.

```
unsigned int input;
unsigned char output;

void main(){
  TRISA = 0x00;
  input = 1000;
  output = (input + 50) / 100; 
  PORTA = output;

  while (1);  //while away once the program is done
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I meant to continue by doing a round function, after asking if the accuracy was important. I wanted to get the casts (sorry transistor, spelling checker has been updated) working first.

Comment: To add, floating point has miserable overhead in a PIC.

Comment: @Mark I know. Its his choice, depends on the needed accuracy.

Comment: Here's an alternate method: I usually add 1/2 the divisor to get correct rounding. That line of code would be "output = (unsigned char)((input + 50)/100);" So that input=150 would become 200/100 = 2 instead of 1 in your original code.

Comment: The answer from TisteAndii is working! I don't need float point accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should have generated a lot of warning messages, specifically about missing casts. Your calculation should be more explicit, and look like this:

output = (int)( (float)input/100.0 );  // a more explicit operation

However, "output" should have been defined as a "short" if the result is only six bits. Since "PORTA" is only 8 bits and "output" is 16 bits, the compiler probably stored the high byte of "output" (a zero) into "PORTA" and stored the low byte (the actual result) in the memory location following "PORTA".

output = (short)( (float)input/100.0 );  // "output" needs to be short

Comment: output = short( (float)input/100.0 ); Does this mean I declare output as a short and input as a float, or does the actual code look like that?

Comment: You do need to define "output" as a "short". But you don't need to define "input" as a "float" - the caste will take care of the conversion for you. You should define "input" as whatever is appropriate for getting its value into the program in the first place.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance Mark, but what is a caste?

Comment: A caste is when you explicitly convert (caste) a variable of one type to another type. "input" is an in "int", but "(float)input" is a float. "(float)input/100.0" is a "float", but "short((float)input/100.0)" is a "short".

Comment: I can't get that to work in MikroC

Comment: OOPS - Sorry, I forgot to put the parentheses around "short". I will update it above. It should be: "output = (short)( (float)input/100.0 ); // "output" needs to be short

Comment: I would recommend using types such as `int16_t` instead of `short`, especially when you really do expect a certain number of bits.

Comment: Spelling, guys, spelling! **cast**, _noun_, an object made by shaping molten metal or similar material in a mould. **caste**, _noun_, each of the hereditary classes of Hindu society, distinguished by relative degrees of ritual purity or pollution and of social status. The former, _cast_, is the one we want. We are "remoulding" the variable into a new form.

Comment: Although definitely better, I'm quite sure "int8_t", "int16_t", etc. are not available with his C compiler, which appears to be based on C90. Those types weren't defined until C99. Although they might exist in that C compiler, I wanted to stick with what I knew would work.